# Message characters greater than 160 giving generic failure on Samsung S3 4.4.2

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am currently working app which is sending messages and also log message send status. I am doing it with following code i am calling sendSMS function with delay of 2 seconds for every phone number. I have tested it many phones and OS versions it is working fine in nexus , lg and samsung but it is causing issue in samsung S3 with OS version 4.4.2. When i send message greater than 160+ chracters to more than one phone numbers it only sent successfully to first phone number and send generic failure to rest of phone numbers. Point to be noted it only occur when i send message of chracters greater than 160. 
Any help would be appreciated

```
  public void sendSMS(final String message, String phoneNo) {
    try {

        String SENT = "com.ebryx.smscustommessagegeneration"+""+System.currentTimeMillis()+""+((int)this.getmMessageId());
        Intent intentMessageASendStatus = new Intent(SENT);

        final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(App.getContext(),  ((int)this.getmMessageId()),
                intentMessageASendStatus, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(){{add(pi);}};

        App.getContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                DatabaseManager dm = new DatabaseManager();
                SendMessageStatus messageStatus = new SendMessageStatus();

                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i("tag","sent successfully ");

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Log.i("tag","Generic Failure");

                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                        Log.i("tag","No service failure");

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

   break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                        Log.i("tag","Airplane mode failure");

                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts,sentPI, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Message Sent", "NOT Send");
        Utils.writeOnLogFile("Message Not Sent: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the delay was there originally to not trigger some kind of "_sending messages too fast_" limit, it might be worth trying with an increased delay between numbers... A 160+ message is sent as two or more separate SMS messages, so it may be the S3 (or that version of Android) is limiting _actual_ messages sent rather than "logical" messages sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , currently i am putting delay of 2 seconds i would increase it. Is there any other reason which may lead messages to generic failure ? Keep in mind that first message full smoothly rest of messages causing trouble.

Comment: I don't **know** how SMS works, so I don't know what else may cause a generic failure. But if there _is_ some form of rate-limiting, then the first message _would_ go through OK but subsequent ones would fail (possibly with a "generic" error) if sent too quickly. Try setting the delay quit large (e.g. 30s) and if that works, reduce it to something more useful.

Comment: i added delay to 40 seconds now 2 messages went and remaining 2 messages causing generic failure. in this way i cannot predict the actual threshold of delay. lets say if user send message to 5 users then what must be the delay. i dont think delay is good answer to it.

Comment: According to [this page I found](http://support.telerivet.com/customer/portal/articles/1981122-increasing-sending-rate-limit) the _default_ Android limit is 30 messages per half-hour on 4.1 or later (i.e. one per minute) or 100 messages per hour on earlier versions (one every 36 seconds) -- both counting the "real" messages (so a 160+ message would count as two or more). That _should_ allow 4 (double) messages every 40s (for a bit), but I know Samsung modify Android quite a bit, so possibly (on some models at least) they limit over a smaller time -- e.g. 4 ("real") messages per two minutes...

Comment: ... unless someone with more specific knowledge sees this question, the safest might be to send one per minute (30/half-hour), remembering to count 160+ messages as two or more). If you try to send them more frequently (because you know you're only going to send 5/10 in total) then you will probably need a "retry" loop for cases like the S3.